# View all CURRENT parameters for a hadoop installation?

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have inherited a hadoop installation and I would like to query all usage parameters and configuration options. I am sifting through the `conf` directory and it is helping, but this is an old installation (1.1.1) and I want to make what certain parameters are even if they are not listed (I know what they *should* be but I would like to validate this). I also would like to make sure if I change things, they actually get changed correctly (so later this would be helpful if I make changes I can query the parameters again and see the reflected changes).

For example, the block size is not specified and I am assuming that it is 64 mb, but I would like to make sure. I don't believe the installation is currently using compression, but I want to view the parameters and make sure, etc.

Is there a way to view these current parameters without digging through documentation on where they *should* be written and, if they are not written, what they *should* be set to as default?